# T-SQL calculate longitude value for 1.0 according specific cordinates

Tags: sql-server, algorithm, t-sql, latitude-longitude, degrees

As I it is shown [here](http://www.zodiacal.com/tools/lat_table.php) the value(how many km is) of one degree of longitude decrease as we move to the poles. I need a algorithm for calculating the current km that one degree of longitude is for given point (longitude and latitude).

Thank in advance.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark  That was very helpful. Why should I started to learn something that will consume too much time, when if I have an example I will try to implement it in the T-SQL. I am sick of negative   opinions, comments and haters.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark I will find a solution in one way or an other, and I will post it here - that will save time in future of people looking for something like this and that's the big benefit that SO brings. So, comments like yours are not helpful and only can offend someone and force him to give up asking questions and eventually answering such. But this is a personal choice after all ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to calculate how many meters is the length of longitude and latitude for a specific geographic point, I use the following algorithm:

```
-- Geograpic Point Cordinates
DECLARE @LATTIDUDE REAL=45
DECLARE @LONGITUDE REAL=45
DECLARE @Distance REAL=10

-- Constants
DECLARE @ConvertionConstant AS FLOAT=2*PI()/360
DECLARE @MetersPerDegree AS FLOAT

DECLARE @LattidueInRadians AS FLOAT=@ConvertionConstant*@LATTIDUDE

DECLARE @LongitudeParameter1 AS FLOAT=111412.84
DECLARE @LongitudeParameter2 AS FLOAT=-93.5 
DECLARE @LongitudeParameter3 AS FLOAT=0.118

SET @MetersPerDegree=(@LongitudeParameter1*COS(@LattidueInRadians))+(@LongitudeParameter2*(COS(3*@LattidueInRadians)))+(@LongitudeParameter3*COS(5*@LattidueInRadians))
DECLARE @LongitudeRangeTemp AS FLOAT=@Distance/(@MetersPerDegree/1000)

-- Results for longitude
SELECT @LongitudeRangeTemp AS DegreesForGivenKM
SELECT @MetersPerDegree    AS MetersPerDegreeOfLongitude

-- Constants
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter1 AS FLOAT=111132.92
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter2 AS FLOAT=-559.82
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter3 AS FLOAT=1.175
DECLARE @LatitudeParameter4 AS FLOAT=-0.0023

-- Results for longitude
SET @MetersPerDegree=(@LatitudeParameter1+(@LatitudeParameter2*COS(2*@LattidueInRadians))+(@LatitudeParameter3*COS(4*@LattidueInRadians))+(@LatitudeParameter4*COS(6*@LattidueInRadians)))
DECLARE @LatitudeRangeTemp AS FLOAT=@Distance/(@MetersPerDegree/1000)
SELECT @LatitudeRangeTemp AS  DegreesForGivenKM
SELECT @MetersPerDegree   AS  MetersPerDegreeOfLatitude
```

An additional parameter is added for kilometers - the code will calculate how many degrees are  are equal to the given kilometers.

You are free to implement the code in function.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually harder than you think, but Google would help with the tricky bits.

However, basically you could use some variation of this:

```
declare @radius as float;
declare @latitude as float;
declare @circumference float;

set @radius = 6378 -- in km
set @latitude = 0 -- 0 = equator : 90 = pole

set @circumference = 2 * pi() * @radius * cos(radians(@latitude))

select @circumference
select (@circumference / 360) as km
select (@circumference / 360) / 1.609344 as miles
```

The tricky bits I alluded to are the facts that the Earth is not a geometric sphere, and isn't perfectly flat - but the above is very roughly right, given that you could use much more accurate radius for example.

**Edit:**

Alternatively, if you have SQL 2008 (or more), you could use the "geography" datatype and the STDistance() function.

```
declare @p1 geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(1 ' + cast(@latitude as varchar(10))+')', 4326)
declare @p2 geography = geography::STPointFromText('POINT(2 ' + cast(@latitude as varchar(10))+')', 4326)

SELECT @p1.STDistance(@p2); -- this is in metres
```

In the above example, it finds the distance between two points at the same latitude, but at a longitude of 1° and a longitude of 2°.